# Integrate custom trained NER model with existing default model in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have trained corpus by following below link.

https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2018-04-25-python-train-model-NTLK-stanford-ner-tagger

Dataset is of some health blog (in English language) on which I've trained. I am successfully able to run this model on my new unseen text.

Problem: The problem I am facing is that I want to run my custom English NER model along with default English model in Stanford CoreNLP.

Desired Outcome: I want Stanford default model to run in sequential manner just after my own custom model NER model to handle those entities in English that are missed by my own model.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp any leads?

Comment: @ChristopherManning Please look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ner.model = /path/to/custom-model.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz
```

There is more info here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

Comment: Thanks @StanfordNLPHelp , It did work but I want to override results of previous model subsequently. There happened to be some entities that are relevant with respect to my country. With my custom model I am annotating those entities/tokens only with custom tags. I want remaining entities to be annotated by default Stanford NER model. Can you please help?

Comment: What is the tag set of your custom model.

Comment: custom model has tags like BRAND, MODEL_NAME, CATEGORY. For example there is a text "L'Oreal  Lotion is a beauty product in USA ." My Custom model should give result as NER [ ('L'Oreal' , 'Brand') , ('Lotion' , '0') , ('is' , 0) , ('a', 0) , ('beauty', 'CATEGORY') , ('product' , 'CATEGORY') , ('USA' , '0). In the above result L'Oreal as brand has been custom annotated along with beauty product as category. As observed mine custom model ignores USA.

Comment: The subsequent NER (default English) model of Stanford should handle this by annotating USA as 'COUNTRY' only overriding those results that have not been handled by my custom model and have been ignored '0'

Comment: That should be the behavior if you set ner.model as I suggested.  It will run each model in sequence.  If the first model has special custom tags only, then the future models in the sequence should operate as normal.

Comment: Will the future models in sequence override the results that have been output as being ignored by first model ? Since right now , this is not happening by following exactly what you've suggested for setting up ner.model.

Comment: Yes subsequent models will overwrite any "O" tags.  If your model is outputting "0" instead of "O" that would cause a problem.

Comment: Thankyou @StanfordNLPHelp, I was making this silly mistake of zero "0" instead of letter "O". I was following a medium blog for training own model there they have misguided by putting wrong information i.e. "Note: Each word needs a label/tag. Here, for words we do not care about we are using the label zero ‘0’."  Link : https://medium.com/swlh/stanford-corenlp-training-your-own-custom-ner-tagger-8119cc7dfc06 . Hope, you can make them rectify on their blog so no one else makes same mistake as me.